# OpenZeppelin: Update UUPS proxy contract

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I have such proxy:

```
import { upgrades } from "hardhat";

proxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(
    Contract,
    [
        address,
        flags,
    ],
    {
        initializer: "initialize",
        kind : "uups",
    }
)
```

And such contract:

```
contract MyContract is UUPSUpgradeable, AccessControlUpgradeable {
    function initialize(
        address streamOwner,
        uint256 _flags,
    ) external initializer {
        __AdminControlled_init(_flags);
    }

    function __AdminControlled_init(uint256 _flags) internal {
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
        __AccessControl_init();
        paused = _flags;
    }

    function _authorizeUpgrade(address)
        internal
        override
        onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE)
    {}
}
```

I am exploring the possibility of updating the proxy contract itself. From my research, it seems that this is not feasible, and the only alternative is to deploy a new proxy contract and migrate the state to it. Can anyone confirm if this understanding is correct or provide any alternative solutions or insights?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly correct.

You normally deploy a new implementation contract (being careful to not overwrite any storage slot) and then point the existing proxy, which is holding the state, to the new implementation contract.

Upgrading the proxy itself does not make a lot of sense, as it just stores state and then delegate calls everything to the implementation contract.

Comment: thx for your answer, I know about usually devs deploys new implementation contract and change implementation address inside proxy contract. But in my case I need to change proxy contract and not implementation

Comment: Why do you need to change the proxy itself? Honestly curious. If thats the case then yes, you will need to deploy the new proxy + implementation and reproduce the state there if thats feasible. Also, if you are using Hardhats upgrades-plugin you will need to deploy manually your proxy instead, as hardhat always deploy OZ's basic Proxy contract as part of the plugins workflow (you can choose between UUPS and Transparent, but the Proxy itself is the same if im not mistaken)